# largest purely inseparable extension (Serre, Local algebra p.46)

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, separable-extension

I am a bit puzzled by the following statement in Serre's local algebra page 46, in the proof of Proposition 16 (https://books.google.com.au/books?id=oZmXsvlYtMQC&pg=PA46&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false). Let me isolate the statement:

Let $K \leq L$ be a finite field extension. By $M \subset L$ we denote the set of elements that are purely inseparable over $K$, i.e., $v \in M$ if and only if $v^{p^r} \in K$ for some $r > 0$. It is not hard to see that $M$ is a field, extending $K$. Then it is claimed that $M \leq L$ is separable ?!

This puzzles, me as I know that one can find $K_{sep}$ such that $K \leq K_{sep}$ is separable and $K \leq L$ is purely inseparable, however I suspect the above can not be true, in fact I vaguely remember counterexamples existing. Can someone help me out about what Serre means here and what I am missing?

Comment: Your $E$ seems to appear out of nowhere. Is this meant to be $M$?

Comment: It is indeed. Fixed.

Comment: I vaguely remember something like that, too. I’ll be interested to see what an expert says about this.

Comment: Serre takes $L/K$ to be normal, so it follows from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2803181/if-l-k-normal-and-h-operatornameautl-k-then-l-lh-is-separable-and?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really does seem to be wrong. There are examples in [an earlier MSE posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1693447/tensor-product-of-purely-inseparable-extension?rq=1). Your question boils down to this: if, in an extension $L\supset K$, the field $L$ has no elements purely inseparable over $K$, is $L$ separable over $K$? And the answer, grâce à Joe Lipman, is *no*.

Comment: Thanks. In that case, is there any way to make Serre's argument work?

Comment: I don’t see any way around the problem. Maybe if the original extension is normal? And note that the two examples there are in characteristic $2$. One should check that a similar construction works in any positive characteristic. But I’m feeling too lazy.