# $I=(f_1, \ldots, f_n)\subset k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ with $f_i\in k[x_i]$ irreducible polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, maximal-and-prime-ideals

> Let $A=k[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ and $I=(f_1, \ldots, f_n)\subset A$ with $f_i\in k[x_i]$ irreducible polynomials. Is it true that $I$ is a maximal ideal in $A$?

$I$ is a maximal ideal $\iff$  $1\in (I, g)$ for every $g\in A\setminus I$ $\iff$ $1\in (I, g)$ for every $g\in A$ with $\deg g<\deg f_i$ $\forall i$ (with the the lexicographical order). Any other ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course not! $A/I\simeq k[x_1]/(f_1)\otimes_k\cdots\otimes_kk[x_n]/(f_n)$, and a tensor product of fields is not necessarily a field. For a concrete (counter)example see [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/345522/121097).

Comment: Do you know where I can find a proof of this isomorphism in your answer?

Comment: Why don't you just look at an example: Let $k=\mathbb{Q}$ and take $f=x^2-2, g=y^2-2$, Both are irreducible but the ideal $I=(f,g)\subset k[x,y]$ is not maximal, since $x^2-y^2\in I$, but $x-y, x+y$ are not in $I$.

Comment: @Mohan Is there something wrong with understanding what's $A/I$ in terms of tensor product of fields?

Comment: Not at all. I mentioned my example just as a starting point, to have an explicit example, if the OP was not yet comfortable with tensor products.